# TypeError: push is not a function

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code for factories.html

```
    af.factory("PurchaseFactory",function(){

    var productlist={products:[]};

    return{
        getpurchaseCart:function(){
            return productlist;
        },
        addPurchaseCart:function(products){
        productlist.products.push(products);

    }

    }
})
```

For Services.html

```
 as.service("PurchaseService",function(PurchaseFactory){

    this.getAllPurchase=function(){
        return PurchaseFactory.getpurchaseCart();
    }
    this.addPurchase=function(products)
    {
        PurchaseFactory.addPurchaseCart(products);
    }
})
```

For Controller.html

```
  ac.controller("PurchaseController",function($scope,PurchaseService){  
     $scope.savepurchase=function(products){
             if($scope.products._id==undefined){            
            $scope.products=angular.extend($scope.products,$scope.sizes)
             PurchaseService.addPurchase($scope.products);
               }       
    }
    }
```

Here i have an another function in the same controller, as

```
$scope.saveorder=function(cartorder){       
    $scope.Mainpurchaselist=angular.extend($scope.cartorder,$scope.getpurchaseList)
         CartService.addPurchaseCart($scope.Mainpurchaselist);
        $scope.getpurchaseList.products={}
         $scope.cartorder={}                                         
         $scope.products={}                                         
      $rootScope.isLogin=false;
     CartService.deletecartyPurchase(idx);
    Notification.success({message: 'your Cart Saving Successfully', delay: 1000});
    }
```

In my HTML file, i have a button with function as savepurchase(products).
For first time its saving data but from second time its showing me error as TypeError:productlist.products.push is not a function. If I refresh the page its again saving the data, but continuously its not working.Let me know where the code goes wrong.
Here $scope.getpurchaselist.products={} is used to make a data null for every new purchase. If I remove the $scope.getpurchaselist.products={}, its working fine with no error but the problem is that the list is not getting null.
SO finally i have two ways 
1. either to make it null by writing $scope.getpurchaselist.products={} but error as productlist.products.push is not a function let me know to overcome that error
2. Or to remove that line and let me know, how to make it null

Comment: Can you add  console.log(productlist.products) before push?

Comment: Yes. I have written it in the controller before adding. I seen the difference is that $hashkey is generating for first time but from second time its not generating. @alpert

Comment: I came across a hint is that to use the track by and stringify options but its not working, any other solution or i try to change the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, $scope.getpurchaseList.products={} is effecting you. As it passing an empty object instead of array as soon as the controller load. So, try removing it.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `if($scope.products._id==undefined)` is breaking you. please check the logic you wrote. keep in mind `$scope.products` and `products` both are different variable in  `savepurchase` function.

After extending `$scope.products` first time, condition return `false`.

Comment: Thank U @Sachink. As you said, I tried the functionality by removing that condition as well as extend also though its having the same error.

Comment: I came across a hint is that to use the track by and stringify options but its not working, any other solution or i try to change the code

Answer (score 0):

change the **$scope.products** into just **products**. because u pass the products as paramater to the savepurchase() function. so no need to define as scope.products in ur controller

Comment: Thanks @Sachila Ranawaka. But i tried that, though is giving me the same error

Comment: can u provide a fiddler or plunker

Comment: Its a bit long code, so not possible with the all fields @sachila Ranawaka

Comment: I came across a hint is that to use the track by and stringify options but its not working, any other solution or i try to change the code@ sachila Ranawaka

Comment: track by $index is use in the ng-repeat directive to avoid the duplicate objects exception. did u try this function without the if condition. only the service call inside the function

Comment: No, not getting how to use it. As i am pushing the objects, where to write it

Comment: i create a plunker with a sample object. check it out. hope this will help out    
https://plnkr.co/edit/YYTKKeA49W6iAhNpdMtC?p=preview

Comment: Thank U @sachila Ranawaka. I have edited my question, can u please check it once. as i want to delete or make a data null if i click on a button

Comment: i think the problem is that before u push the $scope.getpurchaselist.products object in to the array it execute the $scope.getpurchaselist.products={} line because javascript is asynchronous and it doesn't wait until the service is finish. try to use callback function or promise to overcome this

Comment: Absolutely right @Sachila. Really a big thanks for all your hardwork. Now my functionality is working fine with no errors.